# Is there an add (to a list) function for sbcl based common-lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

Hey guys I am trying to break down a complex problem and being able to add an element without creating a list within a list will make the problem MUCH easier. I have done a ton of googling and cannot find any mention to an add function in common-lisp. I should also mention that I am trying to add it to the end of the list.

-I have seen the push macro but that does not compile for whatever reason. I receive an illegal-function call.

-I have tried using cons and that will not work as it will make multiple lists within the main list I am using. I need each element to be in one list so that will not be helpful.

-Using list will create the same problem as cons because I will yet again get layered lists.

There must be some way to add an element to a list without creating layered lists. I am new to lisp so I apologize if this is elementary.

Comment: Show code or you can't be helped with it.  I have no idea how you managed to produce an illegal function call by using `push`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for append.

```
CL-USER> (append '(:a :b :c) '(1 2 3))
(:A :B :C 1 2 3)
```

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_append.htm#append

Comment: Had no idea this function was available. The class I am taking has a notoriously bad professor and a terrible book. Thank you for answering my simple question kindly.

Comment: @user3622073 common lisp is documented in the freely available [hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front). It's big, but accessible and we'll organized. Browsing will find you lots of helpful stuff.

Comment: @user3622073 There are also a couple of books available for free online, i.e. [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/) and [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/).

Answer (score 1):

When working with linked lists (cons cell based lists) it is often helpful to "think backwards". You said you want to add elements to the end of the list, but the optimal way to add something to a linked list is to add it to the front. So if you are able to *turn your problem around* you might use `cons` after all.

For instance, if I where to create a function to build a range as a list I could do this:

```
(defun make-range (from to result)
  (if (<= from to)
    (make-range (1+ from) to (cons from result))
    result))
```

But this would result in a backwards range:

```
* (make-range 1 5 ())
(5 4 3 2 1)
```

However, fixing this is as simple as reversing the list when I'm done building it.

```
(defun make-range2 (from to result)
  (if (<= from to)
    (make-range2 (1+ from) to (cons from result))
    (reverse result)))

* (make-range2 1 5 ())
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Reversing a list *once* is in many cases an overhead we can live with, and something you see a lot in functional programming.